# how to use haskell Control. Exception handle to return a IO(Maybe a)

Tags: haskell

I am reading the real world haskell Chapter 9.
There is a maybeIO function wraps a IO function result into a Maybe:

```
    maybeIO :: IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
    maybeIO act = handle(\_ -> return Nothing) ( liftM Just act)
```

but this code wont work in GHC 7 or +, i wonder how to edit this code so it will work in GHC 7, i tried

```
    import Control.Exception (bracket, handle, SomeException(..))
    maybeIO :: IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
    maybeIO act = handle(\(SomeException e) -> return Nothing) ( liftM Just act)
```

but i got a Parse error: naked expression at top level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't get any such parse error - the only error I got was from missing functions:

```
so3.hs:3:62: Not in scope: `liftM'
```

You need to `import Control.Monad` which is where the `liftM` function is defined.  That or use `fmap` instead of `liftM`.

Your parse error might be due to incorrect indentation, but a copy and paste of your code results in no such issues for me.

Comment: yeah, it works, thanks. Must be other code confused the compiler.